# EventHandler Backspace (two approaches)

Tags: c#, keypress

I want to catch a Backspace control event and delete the last character that my user wrote on a ultracomboEditor.

I've tried both of approaches but they doesnt work..

Approach 1:

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Back)
            OnKeyPress(new KeyPressEventArgs((Char)Keys.Back));


        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Approcah 2:

```
private void ultraComboLeftEyeAxis_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    } 



 this.ultraComboLeftEyeAxis.KeyPress += new System.EventHandler(this.ultraComboLeftEyeAxis_KeyPress);
```

Can you help me?

Comment: what event / key press event are you doing this code on.. you should be using the KeyPress or Key Down Event or even the Key Up even and get at  the KeyChar property...

Comment: Fairly bizarre that a combobox control doesn't already implement backspace.  Use the Infragistics support forum.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know UltraComboEditor but if it is like other combobox classes you could change its text by its *Text* property when the relevant (kind of *ValueChanged*, *TextChanged* or other) event is raised.